# Unable to use Checkjobs and Autocd in Bash 4

Tags: bash, bash4

There are new options in Bash 4: checkjobs and autocd.
However, I did not find documentation for them at

```
man bash
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
{checkjobs,autocd}
```

I found the following in release notes

```
 There is a new `checkjobs` option that causes the shell to check for and
 report any running or stopped jobs at exit
```

and

```
There is a new `autocd` option that, when enabled, causes bash to attempt
to `cd` to a directory name that is supplied as the first word of a
simple command.
```

**How can you use autocd and checkjobs?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`autocd` and `checkjobs` are not commands, but rather, they are options.

They can be set by using the [`shopt` built-in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).

Example:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

and

```
shopt -s checkjobs
```

or

```
shopt -s autocd checkjobs
```

to set both.